# Remove escaping \n

Tags: regex, r

Some data:

```
x <- c("Town\ninfo@notus.com\n\n","\ninfo@notus.com\n","\ninfo@notus.com\n\n","\ninfo@notus.com\n","info@notus.com")
```

This would work but there is word before `\n`

```
gsub("\n","",x,fixed=T)
```

This works but if there isn't `\n` gives `NA`

```
unlist(lapply(regmatches(x,gregexpr("(?<=\n).*",x,perl=TRUE)), function(x) x[1]))
```

EDIT: Desired result:

```
rep("info@notus.com",5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gsub.

```
gsub("(?s)^.*?\\n|\\n.*", "", x, perl=T)
```